# Conky black background kde plasma

Tags: kde, conky

The conky theme has black background. When I tried to remove the background, nothing changes. Even using conky manager2 to change the background to transparent, it still shows black background.

[image: Conky theme with black background]

Below is the conky configuration:

```
conky.config = {
-- Size and Position settings --
    alignment = 'bottom_middle',
    gap_x = 0,
    gap_y = 30,
    maximum_width = 500,
    minimum_height = 300,
    minimum_width = 500,

-- Text settings --
  use_xft = true,
  override_utf8_locale = true,
  font = 'Roboto:size=9',
  
-- Color Settings --
  default_color = '#FFFFFF',
  default_outline_color = 'white',
  default_shade_color = 'white',
  color1 = 'CF557C',
  
-- Window Settings --
  background = false,
  border_width = 1,
  draw_borders = false,
  draw_graph_borders = false,
  draw_outline = false,
  draw_shades = false,
  own_window = true,
  own_window_colour = '000000',
  own_window_class = 'Conky',
  own_window_argb_visual = true,
  own_window_type = 'desktop',
  own_window_transparent = true,
  own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
  stippled_borders = 0,
  
-- Others --
  cpu_avg_samples = 2,
  net_avg_samples = 2,
  double_buffer = true,
  out_to_console = false,
  out_to_stderr = false,
  extra_newline = false,
  update_interval = 1,
  uppercase = false,
  use_spacer = 'none',
  show_graph_scale = false,
  show_graph_range = false,
}

conky.text = [[
${execi 300 ~/.config/conky/Sadachbia-Dark/scripts/weather-v2.0.sh}\
${image ~/.config/conky/Sadachbia-Dark/res/Hour.png -s 100x50 -p 130,240}\
${image ~/.config/conky/Sadachbia-Dark/res/Minute.png -s 100x50 -p 260,240}\
${alignc}${voffset 0}${color1}${font Bebas Neue:size=160}${time %d}${font}
${alignc}${voffset -80}${color}${font Dosis:size=30}${time %A & %B}${font}
${alignc 43}${voffset 63}${color}${font Dosis:bold:size=20}${time %I}${font}
${alignc -88}${voffset -33}${color}${font Dosis:bold:size=20}${time %M}${font}
${alignc}${voffset 18}${color}${font Great Vibes:size=35}${time %^p}${font}
${alignc}${voffset 35}${color}${font Dosis:bold:size=22}${execi 60 cat ~/.cache/weather.json | jq -r '.name' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'} ${font}
${alignc}${voffset 5}${color}${font Dosis:size=11}${execi 60 cat ~/.cache/weather.json | jq -r '.weather[0].main' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/'} WITH TEMPERATURE ${execi 60 cat ~/.cache/weather.json | jq '.main.temp' | awk '{print int($1+0.5)}'} °C${font}
${alignc}${voffset 0}${color}${font Dosis:size=11}WIND SPEED ${execi 60 (cat ~/.cache/weather.json | jq '.wind.speed')}MPS AND HUMIDITY ${execi 160 (cat ~/.cache/weather.json | jq '.main.humidity')}%${font}
]]
```